# css file for pandas - correlation table

Tags: python, css, pandas, pyqt5, qtwebengine

When I write code with jupyter:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path..")
corr = df.corr()
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```

I will get table with color and styling. However, when I add style and render it.

```
style_html = corr.style.render()
print(corr.style.render())
```

I could see the output :

...
style  type="text/css"  /style  etc.

Note: I removed<> from above html code
...

check HTML (png):

[image: output after render]

I noticed here system taking text/css file. But I don't know where this css file available and I am guessing because CSS file not available in my local drive. So, when I pass syntax after render to QWebEngineView it shows plain output. So someone please help me how to get correlation table with color and styling in QwebEngineView

[image: Plain output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the background_gradient you are not modifying the default Styler but creating a new one, therefore you must obtain the html of that new Styler:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(0.2, 0.3), (0.0, 0.6), (0.6, 0.0), (0.2, 0.1)], columns=["dogs", "cats"]
)
corr = df.corr()
style_html = corr.style.background_gradient(cmap="coolwarm").render()

web.setHtml(style_html)
web.resize(320, 120)
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your observation is awesome.

Comment: I really amazed with your answers and profile. I want learn more on pyqt5. will you teach pyqt5 to me, I will pay money as well. Please let me know waiting for your reply.